# Remove negative sign in string format in python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

i'd like to know if it is possible to remove the negative sign from `'{:,.2f}'.format(number)` only using format.

So that

`'{:,.2f}'.format(10) ## 10`

`'{:,.2f}'.format(-10) ## 10`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't with `str.format()` or `format()` alone. Use [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs) on the number instead:

```
'{:,.2f}'.format(abs(value))
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `abs`

```
 '{:,.2f}'.format(abs(-10))
```

Or `lstrip`:

```
num = -10
print '{:,.2f}'.format(num).lstrip("-")
10.00
```

Or:

```
num = -10
print 'Your number is: {:,.2f}'.format(num).replace("-","")
```

Comment: Stripping only works if the number is at the start of the resulting string; if the format is `'Your number is: {:,.2f}'` instead you have a problem than only `abs()` can solve..

Comment: abs() will not work if you have a number with decimal point like -10.0, but lstrip does